# TreeItem with I18N GWT

Tags: gwt, tree, history, token, gwt-history

I am wondering how to build a TreeItem with I18N and not have different tokens for a menu item.

If I build a TreeItem like this:

```
 @UiField
    Tree tree;

    TreeItem customer = new TreeItem(customerGroup");
       customer.addItem("searchCustomer");
       customer.addItem("create");
       customer.setState(true);

                            tree.clear();
   tree.addItem(customer);


                  @UiHandler("tree")
  public void onSelection(SelectionEvent<TreeItem> event) {
    eventBus.fireEvent(event);
   }
```

the ValueChange token I get when a user clicks the "create" node is "create" and then I get code like

```
 public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {
  String token = event.getValue();
     if(token.equals("create") 
    {
    CreateCustomerView create = new CreateCustomerView(eventBus,
         customerService);
       content.setContent(create);
    }
```

...

But what if I want to have different languages in the TreeItem nodes, then I want something other then the text as a token, perhaps an id. Can I solve this with the Places pattern from the MVP pattern, and if so how does that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `TreeItem` there are 2 method `setUserObject(Object userObject)` and `getUserObject`. You can use those to or set an Id, which you than can use to check against. However, I don't see how you come from a `SelectionEvent` to the `ValueChangeEvent`. You lose some information in between.

Comment: eventBus.fireEvent(event); in the tree fire an SelectionEvent, that gets picked up by the onValueChange event in the another class

Comment: Thanks Hilbrand, your solution worked. setting the userObject when creating the treeItem and picking it up when I create the histroyToken from a onSelection event method.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you compare the selected item attached to the `SelectionEvent` with the items you added previously? Something like this:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    Tree tree = new Tree();
    final TreeItem item1 = new TreeItem("item 1");
    TreeItem item2 = new TreeItem("item 2");
    TreeItem item3 = new TreeItem("item 3");
    TreeItem item4 = new TreeItem("item 4");

    tree.addItem(item1);
    tree.addItem(item2);
    tree.addItem(item3);
    tree.addItem(item4);

    tree.addSelectionHandler(new SelectionHandler<TreeItem>() {

        @Override
        public void onSelection(SelectionEvent<TreeItem> event) {
            if (event.getSelectedItem().equals(item1)) {
                Window.alert("item1 selected");
            }
        }
    });

    RootPanel.get().add(tree);
}
```

Or am I missing something?